# String value becomes is null inside called function

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, promise, bluebird

There is something really weird happening in my code, I am passing a value to a function. But inside that function the value is null and I cannot understand why. I was expecting to get a proper value and not null.

Inside the validateCampaingKeywords function when I call AdwordsService.isKeywordsCampaign I can see that the value of campaign.customerId is defined and is "1624183869"

```
function validateCampaingKeywords(req){
  return function(campaign){
     return AdwordsService
       .isKeywordsCampaign(campaign.customerId,req.user.googleRefreshToken)
       .then((isKeywordsCapaign) =>{
          return {revert:!isKeywordsCapaign}
       });
  }
}
```

[image]

but when I check wich value it has inside the called function, it is undefined.

```
export function isKeywordsCampaign(accountId,customerRefreshToken){
  let lastWeekDate = new Date();
  lastWeekDate.setDate(lastWeekDate.getDate() - 7);
  return getCampaingsRawData(accountId,customerRefreshToken,lastWeekDate)
                  .then(campaignReportToCampaignDataConverter.convert).then((totalSpentValue) => {
      return totalSpentValue > 0;
    });
}
```

[image]

the weirdest part to me comes now. if I am inside the invoked function and check what is the value of arguments[0], it gives me the correct value;

[image]

this is the first function called inside my controller, here I just find the given campaign and update it.

```
  // Upserts the given Campaign in the DB at the specified ID
        export function upsert(req, res) {
          if(req.body._id) {
            delete req.body._id;
          }
          return Campaign.findOneAndUpdate({_id: req.params.id}, req.body, {new: true, upsert: true, setDefaultsOnInsert: true, runValidators: true}).exec()
            .then(validateCampaingKeywords(req))
            .then(respondWithResult(res))
            .catch(handleError(res));
        }
```

Does anyone know why this is happening?

Comment: Certainly very odd. The only thing that would make any sense is for the two appearances of 'accountId' not to match - ie typographic error. But that appears not to be the case. For good measure, try retyping or copy/pasting.

Answer (score -1):

Debugging is a series of bifurcations (dividing into two sets) of all the possible causes for differences between expected and observed behavior.  To eliminate potential issues with the compiler or the IDE or interactions with the -> operator, don't so instantly use the functions return value via the dot operator.  Instead place it in an object reference first.

> keywordsCampaignFlag = isKeywordsCampaign(campaign.customerId,req.user.googleRefreshToken);

Log the value of campaign.customerId before it is passed as a parameter and after it is presented as an argument inside the method.  If the log entries show the same value, then your problem is in the expression from which you pulled the function.  If not, then the method call mechanism is misbehaving for some reason.